# consulta sql para obtener campos de la misma tabla pero en diferentes relaciones

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional, diagrama-er

tengo por un lado la tabla usuario relacionada con venta, y por el otro relacionada con producto. Quiero obtener el usuario que compro y el que vendió. El modelo de tablas es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi consulta:

```
select concat(u.nombre, ' ', u.apellido) As comprador, concat(us.nombre, ' ', us.apellido) As vendedor
from usuario u
inner join venta v on u.id = v.comprador_id
inner join detalle d on v.id = d.venta_id
inner join producto p on d.producto_id = p.id
inner join usuario us on p.usuario_id = us.id;
```

No obtengo resultados. ¿cómo puedo referirme a los campos de usuario, en un contexto comprador y en otro vendedor? Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Una posible solución es en tu tabla de usuario tener un tipo de usuario para que sepas como distinguir de comprador y vendedor, y a su vez en tu tabla de venta tendrías que almacenar dos veces el usuario (comprador_id - vendedor_id) para ahora si poder referirte a un comprador y un vendedor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La estructura de datos no ayuda mucho, si este es un caso habitual. En aquellos casos donde el usuario-venta sea distinto del usuario-producto efectivamente no devolverá resultados.

Una solución es realizar dos consultas por separado y unirlas por un `join`, puesto que comparten en común la venta. En la primera obtienes el comprador, en la segunda el vendedor de cada venta/detalle/producto.

```
select a.comprador, b.vendedor
from (
   select v.id, concat(u.nombre, ' ', u.apellido) As comprador
   from usuario u
   inner join venta v on u.id = v.comprador_id
   inner join detalle d on v.id = d.venta_id
   inner join producto p on d.producto_id = p.id
) a
inner join (
   select v.id, concat(us.nombre, ' ', us.apellido) As vendedor
   from venta v
   inner join detalle d on v.id = d.venta_id
   inner join producto p on d.producto_id = p.id
   inner join usuario us on p.usuario_id = us.id;
) b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por su tiempo,saludos!!!